# Why does max(array_push()) not find max?

Tags: php, arrays, max, array-push

Up front, I would like to clarify that I am *not* looking for a workaround to find max--I already have the solution for accomplishing that goal. What I am curious about is *why* `max(array_push())` doesn't work.

I have an array with many values in it, and want to find the max of specific values within that array. Existing array:

```
$array1 = array(2,6,1,'blue','desk chair');
```

The basic idea is to create a new array consisting of those specified values, and then find the max of that new array. I attempted to make this effort operate all on one line:

```
$max = max(array_push($array2, $array1[0], $array1[1], $array1[2]));
//this doesn't work at all, since $array2 doesn't already exist, as per the PHP manual
```

I changed to code to first create `$array2`, but didn't assign values at that time, just to see if the code works.

```
$array2 = array();
$max = max(array_push($array2, $array1[0], $array1[1], $array1[2]));
//$array2 is populated, but $max is not assigned
```

The obvious solution is to assign values to `$array2` at creation and then use `max()` by itself. I'm just curious as to why `max(array_push())` doesn't find max, since compounded functions normally operate from inside to outside.

Thank you.

Comment: *"What I am curious about is why `max(array_push())` doesn't work."* -- were you curious enough to read the documentation of [`array_push()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-push.php)? It return an integer: the new number of elements in the array.

Comment: Actually, it will work for all cases where *the maximum of the values pushed into the array* is equal to *the number of elements pushed into the array*, hehe!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`max` needs an array to work with but `array_push` returns an integer and actually uses the provided array by reference, you have to do :

```
$array2 = array();
array_push($array2, $array1[0], $array1[1], $array1[2])
$max = max($array2);
```

Alternatively do:

```
$array2 = array($array1[0], $array1[1], $array1[2]);
$max = max($array2);
```

A 3rd option (though not the cleanest one):

```
$array2 = array();
$max = max($array2 = array_merge($array2, [$array1[0], $array1[1], $array1[2]]));
```

For reference, see:

- http://php.net/manual/en/function.max.php
- http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-push.php

Comment: There's also just `max($array1[0], $array1[1], $array1[2])` - you don't need to bother with creating a new array at all.

Comment: @iainn unless OP intends to use the created array somewhere else further down the code

Comment: @iainn I didn't realize that I could supply individual indices to max(). That would actually be more efficient.

Comment: @apokryfos No, I don't intend to use $array2 for anything else. See my comment to iainn.

Comment: @apokryfos Thank you for this explanation. I failed to notice the part in the manual mentioning what array_push() actually returns. Strangely, I had considered Option 3, but figured that creating a variable with a stated value (using an "=") inside a simple function would throw an exception. Yeah, I don't program much.

Answer (score 0):

You could also use `array_slice()`:

```
$max = max(array_slice(
    $array1,
    0,
    3
));
```

if

- the values you are interested in are in a sequence
- you know *offset* and *length* of the sequence

For reference, see:

- http://php.net/manual/de/function.array-slice.php
- http://php.net/manual/de/function.max.php

For an example, see:

- https://3v4l.org/nMK1Z